# Web Browsers Opening Multiple SSL connections for one request

Tags: ssl, https, connection, browser

I have a RESTful API and when I use a web browser, IE Chrome or Firefox, to send a GET request I noticed that the browsers sometimes opens 2 connections.  One connection seems to always get to the change cipher finished part of the SSL handshake and then closes connection before request can be completed.  The other connection is able to get past the change cipher finished part of the SSL handshake and complete the GET request.  Which connection fails doesn't depend on which connection was established first.

Why are the browsers sending the 2 request? Why is it dropping one of the request after the change cipher complete part of the SSL handshake?

I would post image of packet capture, but I do not have enough reputation to do that.  Any help on this would be much appreciated.